# MYSQL NOT IN array php

Tags: php

Olá, senhores

Estou trabalhando em um projeto para um hobby que tenho e estou tendo uma dificuldade com a parte do MYSQL. Possuo uma array que vem da API e é decodificada e insere alguns dados das conexões no DB. Até aí, tudo normal. Porém, as conexões serão fechadas posteriormente - afinal os clientes irão desconectar-se da rede. Preciso que esses registros sejam apagados do DB, e então pensei em utilizar o NOT IN do MySQL. Pesquisando na internet, percebi que teria de utilizar o implode do php para poder adequar-me ao formato do MYSQL. Sendo assim, criei:

```
$comma_separated = "'" implode("", $csv[$i]) "'" ;
//Comando SQL - Remove do DB aeronaves que não partem do Brasil
$sql = "DELETE FROM connections WHERE callsign not in ('$comma_separated')";
```

Onde, csv é a array com os dados - o $i vem de um loop que busca os dados da API. O problema é que ao executar o código ele simplesmente apaga todos os registros, inclusive aqueles que ainda possuem o callsign na array.

Como procedo nessa situação? Já pesquisei em vários lugares, inclusive aqui no próprio StackOverflow e não achei nenhuma referência.

Desde já, agradeço e gostaria de informar e peço perdão por qualquer código bizarro. Sou iniciante na linguagem. Para aqueles que quiserem ver mais alguma parte do código, está upado no GitHub pela url:
[github.com/SirGwaihir/parsec](http://github.com/SirGwaihir/parsec)

Abraço

Comment: Experimente  $comma_separated = implode("','", $csv[$i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente precisa de aspas simples e vírgula:

```
$comma_separated = implode("','", $csv[$i]);
```

Precisa ver também se o `$csv[$i]` é realmente o que você quer.

Um código de demonstração. Use `echo` para evitar testes no DB:

```
$lista = array( 'PY2UFO', 'PY2VB' );
$comma_separated = implode("','", $lista);
$sql = "DELETE FROM connections WHERE callsign not in ('$comma_separated')";
echo $sql;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/KvAPmL)**.

Comment: Vale notar que olhando seu código no github tenho a impressão que já tem algum probleminha anterior. Certifique-se de juntar todos os `callsign`s num _array_ só antes de usar o código acima. Um `print_r( $lista );` é um bom meio de verificar e acertar o problema ANTES de testar o código acima.

Comment: Olá, @Bacco. Creio que esse realmente seja o grande problema. O fato de não ter conseguido juntar todos os callsigns em uma array só. Você teria alguma sugestão? Já tentei fazer do jeito comum, como `array($callsign)`; porém ele cria uma array para cada callsign o que não é nem de perto o que quero. Fazendo os testes com o que você sugeriu percebi que a solução seria realmente adicionar todos os callsigns a uma mesma array, mas não sei como.
Abraço

Comment: faça um loop que pegue os callsigns e use assim `$lista[] = $csv[237]` (no lugar do $csv[237]  você usa o campo correto). Terminado o loop, você vai ter todas as ocorrencias em $lista. O [] = no final da variavel significa "adicione no array".

Comment: Ok, testarei e assim que tiver algum resultado lhe reporto. Muito obrigado pelo apoio :D

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, Bacco. O problema realmente era esse. Vi pelo var_dump que os callsigns estavam na forma de string. Segui seus passos e consegui transformar para um array. Agora está funcionando tudo show de bola. Valeu pelo apoio. Abraço :D

Answer (score 0):

Olhando superficialmente, nota-se a falta do delimitador.

```
implode("", $csv[$i])
```

troque por

```
implode("', '", $csv[$i])
```

## Dica

Antes de executar a query, verifique a integridade fazendo um breakpoint:

logo após essa linha

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM connections WHERE callsign not in ('$comma_separated')";
```

adicione

```
echo $sql; exit;
```

Isso é apenas para visualizar como a query está sendo montada.

Se estiver montando corretamente, desabilite o teste ou apague.

```
//echo $sql; exit;
```

<sub>Note que as dicas acima podem não resolver o problema 100%. É uma dica de solução baseada na hipótese mais provável, segundo o que apresentou na questão.</sub>